# How to search from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a charges model and a transaction model

I am using ransack gem to handle my search

I want to search for items in the charges model from the transaction side

I have this piece on my transaction view because I want to see charges on my transactions page.

```
<%= tag.fieldset do %>
    <%= tag.legend 'Search Price' %>
    <%= tag.ul do %>
      <%= tag.li do %>
        <%= f.label :Revenue %>
        <%= f.text_field :revenue_cont %>
      <% end %>
      <%= tag.li do %>
        <%= f.label :Agency %>
        <%= f.text_field :agency_cont %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>


<p>The rate is </p>
<% @charges.each do |charge| %>
  <td><%= charge.rates %></td>
<% end %>
```

and my transaction controller looks like this

```
def new
    @q = Charge.search(params[:q])
    @charges = @q.result

    @transaction = Transaction.new
  end
```

whenever I search, it doesn't show the search result and the link is '127.0.0.1' but when I do '127.0.0.1/transactions/new?q%5Brevenue_cont%5D=1356&q%5Bagency_cont%5D=2468&commit=Search' it shows the search result

How can I make it attach the search parameter in the link.

Answer (score 1):

When you put your URL (**127.0.0.1/transactions/new?q%5Brevenue_cont%5D=1356&q%5Bagency_cont%5D=2468&commit=Search**) directly in browser address bar, you send query param `q`. So `ransack` works.

But when you simply go to `new` action, your `params[:q]` is blank. So `ransack` doesn't work and page is rendered without needed data.

One of the way to resolve it -- make asynchronous request to server. You need to use JavaScript for this (ajax, fetch, axios).

Comment: I don't know Javascript

I'd love it if in my ```new``` action once I put in what I want to search for, the search params get's added to the link. I think it's a controller issue but I am not sure.